# How to process javascript for scraping in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make a script to extract a url from a site. As I understand this url is generated by javascript when the user click the "play" button (it's an audio stream url). I know that  mechanize python module doesn't support javascript. Then what should I use to detect the url from that button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use beautifulsoup --
https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/
[https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:~:text=Beautiful%20Soup%20is%20a%20Python,hours%20or%20days%20of%20work](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=Beautiful%20Soup%20is%20a%20Python,hours%20or%20days%20of%20work).

It's very easy.